# LocalSessionFactoryBean hitting BasicDataSource with "sa" username

Tags: spring, hibernate, apache-commons-dbcp, mariadb

Here's the configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${connection.driverclass}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${connection.url}/${connection.database}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${connection.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${connection.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:path/to/hibernate/mappings/*.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Everything works as expected when I deploy in-place using IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), but when I deploy to stand-alone Tomcat 7, BasicDataSource throws UnsuportedOperationException.

Debugging showed that the exception is thrown because the BasicDataSource:getConnection is called with username 'sa', further showing that LocalSessionFactoryBean is getting instantiated with that username. I'm completely baffled by this since I can't find where the username gets injected.

I'm using MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

There was a tests JAR in Infinispan Hibernate dependency that contained hibernate.properties file that got loaded.